# Opera dmg corrupt

Tags: data-transfer, dmg, opera

I have been trying to download the Opera DMG from my Mac OSX on a very slow internet.
Everytime, the download starts, reaches a little above 1 MB, and then shows as download complete. When I try opening the DMG, it says that it is not recognized.

Downloads work fine on all other sites except Opera.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: Hi Welcome to AskDifferent. Yeah, you should use a decent browser. (Sorry - just jokes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the download is timing out. The Opera mirrors you are downloading from might be suffering issues or it might be your ISP's connection which you pay for. You might need to wait a while so that the issues on Opera's side (if it is their side) gets fixed or you may want to look for an alternate place to download the DMG.

Comment: It just happens for the Opera website. Not for anything else. I guess I'll download it from CNET or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As James points out the download is timing out.

For the current version of [Opera](http://www.opera.com/computer/thanks?partner=www&par=id=36322&location=360&gaprod=opera) you should be downloading a file that is at least 55.7 Mb large.

[image]